# Ping Fed :How to re-direct back from Idp login page to Sp asp .net application to receive posted SAMLResponse?

Tags: .net, redirect, ping, saml-2.0

I am going to use Ping Federate for authenticating my existing asp .net web application. 
My application stands as Sp. I have a link to the IDp page.
The link looks like this (`https://fed1.sys.xxxxxx.xx/idp/startSSO.ping?PartnerSpId=xx-xxxx-xxxx`).

This is where the user enters their credentials. After authentication the SAMLResponse is posted back to my 
asp .net application(which is the Sp).

I have the following challenges;

1. How to call Idp page from my asp .net application page?
2. After that how can I receive the SAMLResponse on the page to continue with the execution?

**Note:** I tried

```
Response.Redirect("https://fed1.sys.xxxxxx.xx/idp/startSSO.ping?PartnerSpId=xx-xxxx-xxxx")
```

so the page
is redirecting to the IDp login page. But after that how will I catch the SAMLResponse back on my page?

On the chrome  debugger I an see the SAMLResponse posted back as Response but how to grab it on my `Default.aspx.cs` page is the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to grab the posted response on my page by setting Response.Redirect(url,false);

After that I did an HttpRequest, Request["SAMLResponse"]

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. To call the Idp using the SAML2 protocol you should issue an AuthnRequest. An SAML2 SP (Service Provider) module will help you do that correctly.
2. You should use a SAML2 SP (Service Provider) module to receive and validate the SAML2 response and establish a user session.

So what you need is an SP implementation. There are several available options, both commercial and open source.